# Filter CI trigger in TFS vnext build to a subfolder of git repo

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

In the new TFS build system, I want to configure a continuous integration trigger to only trigger for a subfolder within a git repo.  Is this possible?  How would I do it?  I've tried a number of formats for the filter field and nothing has worked so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to limit the CI trigger to a specific folder within the repo. There is a feature request on the Microsoft UserVoice site, you can vote it:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5279254-allow-git-ci-builds-to-monitor-changes-only-in-a-s

Comment: This, unfortunately, seems to be the answer for now.  Thanks Vicky,

Answer (score 2):

You can do it now with path filters: https://blog.gavryli.uk/2016/06/16/vsts-tfs-trigger-build-only-on-push-to-git-subfolder/

Comment: Great to hear!  This question was specific to TFS, but if it's now in VSTS I expect we'll see this feature on-prem soon!